# Azure WebJobs - no longer working. No route registered for

Tags: azure-webjobs

From 4am this morning. Two of my webjobs that have been running quite happily for months every 2 minutes are now broken. The error is:

> Http Action - Response from host
>   '*******************.scm.azurewebsites.net': 'NotFound' Response
>   Headers: Pragma: no-cache x-ms-request-id:
>   d719e8d0-429d-4ba3-86de-a732e54dbd4f Cache-Control: no-cache Date:
>   Wed, 21 Sep 2016 21:20:01 GMT Set-Cookie:
>   ARRAffinity=8f119d7b3e71f6a6a4d78b9eebbac59d8f13ae47ad9ddc5efdc9151826e5ad57;Path=/;Domain=********************.scm.azurewebsites.net
>   Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0 X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 X-Powered-By:
>   ASP.NET  Body: "No route registered for
>   '/api/triggeredwebjobs/batch/run%3Farguments=job-steve'"

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API#invoke-a-triggered-job
http://blog.davidebbo.com/2015/05/scheduled-webjob.html

I am using David Ebbo's solution in the above link and also adding parameters as outlined on the project website.

Comment: Can you share your web app name, either directly or [indirectly](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly)? This will help us investigate. Thanks!

Comment: Also, can you specify what timezone '4am' refers to?

Comment: Thanks David, good article BTW.  pyramiswebjobs.azurewebsites.net.  4am was European time on Wednesday morn, so 5am in London.  I have deleted and republished to this test site and added a new scheduler.  Both Production and this have the same issue, so must be some kind of update?

Comment: What happens if you go to the Azure Portal and try to manually run the WebJobs? Right now, logs show that this PyramisBatch WebJob has never run at all in this WebApp.

Comment: Just run it, works fine.  It complains about no parameters but that is correct.  The errors I see are in the scheduler.

Comment: It's a name mismatch. See my Answer below.

Comment: I wonder if it's an encoding issue on the client (i.e. Azure Scheduler) side, as it's showing the ? as %3F in the error. Can you try manually invoking the WebJob with the argument using a test client like PostMan or curl? It seems to work fine for me on my test WebJob.

Comment: You're right David.  I have updated it with a ? and not %3F and it now works.  What I can't work out is that I never put %3F in either of them and looking at what I copied out for release docs it did copy out as %3F.  Obviously a portal thing at some point, but it has worked fine until this morning.  If you post as the answer, I will give you the answer, thanks for your time and help.  Very annoying issue that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we discovered, the root issue was that the '?' in the URL was encoded as `%3F`, instead of just being `?`. Fixing the URL in the scheduler addressed the issue.

What's not clear is what caused it to be that way if it used to work. That could be some kind of scheduler or portal issue. But at least we know it's not something related to WebJob itself.

Comment: I don't understand how you resolved this issue? Did change something and redeploy the job? How do you "fix the url in the scheduler" ?

Comment: What you're running into now is unrelated to this question. Please see [forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/e046ef98-ae3a-4942-819f-b62e1775b533/app-service-customers-trying-to-run-a-triggered-webjob-manually-may-see-failures-and-error-message?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) and follow up there.

Comment: @Shane that issue is now resolved, so you should no longer see this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a mismatch between the name of the WebJob that your scheduler is trying to invoke (`batch`), and the actual name of your WebJob in your Web App (`PyramisBatch`). So the error is expected.

Can you change you scheduler to hit the right WebJob?

Comment: Sorry David, that was my fault I should have put **** instead of deleting for the post and sending you on the wrong track.  It still doesn't work, however I have created a new schedule and if I stop at /run it works, if I add the parameters in then it fails with the error as described.

Comment: Ok, so it's something with the parameter. I'll look into that angle.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my web api app. Restarting the app fixed it.